# What to do when an animal dies inside a hollow tree?

Tags: tree-care, raccoons

We have a beautiful Shag Bark Hickory next to the house with a large hole about 18' up.  A family of raccoons moved in a few weeks ago and had a litter.  Recently we've seen a lot of domestic disturbance going on as the mother fought off the father.  Well, I can only assume he's gotten to the kids and killed them.  The tree is starting to smell and we see flies around it.

I don't want to cut down the tree, it's beautiful.  I know it's hollow.  It won't last forever but I still don't want to cut the tree.

What do we do about the scent?  Is there a way to not have to endure it?  Concrete?  Flesh eating beetle?

What advice, please?

Answer (score 10):

Time and flies will take care of the problem with you, if you can wait a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 3):

Greebo is right, time heals all wounds.  However, if you can't handle the smell and flies, you can try dumping a gallon or two of ground limestone down the hole.  I'm not really sure how it will effect what's left of the tree, but it will cut down the smell, maybe keep other predators away and help dry out the remains in the tree. Anyone want some lime jerky?

Comment: Well, Homes, that's the million dollar question;  will Lime hurt the tree?

Comment: most likely, seeing as lime is extremely basic.